# A doubt on how $l_p$ is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading the reflexivity in functional analysis. The book that I'm referring it proves $l_p* \cong (l_p)^* $ by sending $y \to f_y$ and it proves that this map is an isometry. Similarly, it proves that $(l_p*)^* \cong l_p$, It is clear that $l_p \cong (l_p)^{**}$ but how do I know that it is reflexive? For that one has to use the map $x \to J_x$ where $J_x$ is an evaluation map. I'm really confused here. Can someone provide me with some insights? Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure how to read $l_p*$. Perhaps you mean $l_{p^*}$ (with the asterisk a superscript within the subscript) and then $p^*$ is defined to mean $1/(1-1/p)=p/(p-1)$, so that $1/p+1/p^*=1$? Because then the statement $l_{p^*}\cong(l_p)^*$ would be true.

Comment: I assumed that this is what it means in my answer below.

Comment: @TobyBartels I forgot to mention that. Yes p* is the conjugate of p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good that you understand that just because $ V \cong V ^ { * * } $, that doesn't mean that $ V $ is reflexive!  That's a subtlety that a lot of people will miss, and perhaps your book is rushing through this without addressing it.

You didn't give a lot of details about how the proof is done, but you'll have look at them to see why the map $ x \mapsto J _ x $ from $ l _ p $ to $ ( l _ p ) ^ { * * } $ is the same as the isometric isomorphism from $ l _ p $ to $ ( l _ p ) ^ { * * } $ that you get from composing the two simpler maps $ y \mapsto f _ y $.  And even defining that composite is a little tricky, since while one factor is $ l _ { p ^ * } \cong ( l _ p ) ^ * $ itself, the other factor is what you get when you apply the dual to $ ( l _ { p ^ * } ) ^ * \cong l ^ p $.  So you need to bring in a proof that $ V ^ * \cong W ^ * $ whenever $ V \cong W $ to really complete that.

It might actually be simpler to create your own direct proof that $ x \mapsto J _ x $ is an isometric isomorphism by using the proof that $ y \mapsto f _ y $ is an isometric isomorphism as a guide, rather than to derive it as a corollary.  But the details of how this looks will depend on the details of how the proof in your book looks (since this can be proved in a few different ways).

Comment: Thanks a lot I got the idea. My book didn't give me much it only said that the map is identity and it confused me more. Thanks again